# Casting to void doesn't remove warn_unused_result error

Tags: c, gcc, gcc-warning

In a test, I'm discarding anything from `stderr` since it clutters the output of the test case. I'm using the following code:

```
freopen("/dev/null", "w", stderr);
```

When compiling with `-Wall -Werror`, I get the error

```
error: ignoring return value of ‘freopen’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result
```

which is expected. However, the usual solution of casting to `void` doesn't seem to work. That is, changing the code to

```
(void) freopen("/dev/null", "w", stderr);
```

still produces the same warning. I don't care if this function fails since the worst case scenario is a bit of extra output. Any other way I can fix this?

**EDIT:** I know I could introduce an extra unnecessary variable. I would really like to know why casting to void doesn't work.

**UPDATE:**
I decided to go with this:

```
FILE *null = fopen("/dev/null", "w");
if (null) { fclose(stderr); stderr = null; }
```

After reading the `freopen` documentation more carefully, I see that if opening `/dev/null` fails, `stderr` will still be destroyed. This solves that problem.

Comment: 'null' is a bad name for a C variable.

Comment: Good point. I don't know what I thought that was a good idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not simply use the result, as the warning suggests you should.

```
if (freopen("/dev/null", "w", stderr) == 0)
    ...oops...lost stderr...hard to report errors...
```

Since the function is declared with the 'warn_unused_result' attribute, you will get the warning unless you use the return value.  Since the function either returns null on failure or the file stream argument on success, you might think about assigning the result.  However, you should not
assign to stderr like that (see below), so this is a bad idea:

```
stderr = freopen("/dev/null", "w", stderr);
```

Theoretically, you should make that check; there are dire (and implausible) circumstances under which you could fail to open "/dev/null".

---

Footnote 229 in the C99 standard notes:

> <sup>229)</sup> The primary use of the `freopen` function is to change the file associated with a standard text stream
>   (`stderr`, `stdin`, or `stdout`), as those identifiers need not be modifiable lvalues to which the value
>   returned by the `fopen` function may be assigned.

Therefore, the assignment is ill-advised.  But testing the return value would deal with the compiler warning and might help prevent core dumps too.  It is unlikely to improve your code coverage figures, though (the error path is not going be taken very often; it will be hard to force coverage of the error handling).

Note that the POSIX description of [`freopen()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/freopen.html) has some moderately caustic comments about the design of `freopen()`, which was invented by the C standard committee (1989 version), presumably without input from POSIX.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Using the result may be applicable for the given examples, but there are enough cases where one explicitly wants to ignore the result. Declaring variables just to throw them away is not a good workaround...

Answer (score 12):

A little heavy on the GCC extensions, but no externally visible variables:

```
#define ignore_result(x) ({ typeof(x) z = x; (void)sizeof z; })
ignore_result(freopen("/dev/null", "w", stderr));
```

Comment: I would suggest to use __typeof__() instead of typeof().

Answer (score 2):

```
int tossmeout = freopen("/dev/null", "w", stderr);
```

As comments below try

```
FILE *tossmeout = freopen("/dev/null", "w", stderr);
```

and

```
(void *)freopen("/dev/null", "w", stderr);
```

Comment: Sure. But is there a way to do this without creating an unnecessary variable?

Comment: Also, `freopen` returns `FILE*`.

Comment: @Michael : most compilers won't "create" a variable -- they just put it in a symbol table and only reserve space for it if it is referenced.   -- they *might* be lazy increment the stack pointer for local storage.

Comment: Sure. When I said "create a variable" I meant in the source code.

Comment: @Michael : Wow, one week more and it would have been exactly a year.  Remember, the goal of source code is to be easy to use and maintain.  If the compiler is going to optimize it then why stress?

Comment: I don't know why I came back to this. You're right I suppose. But I always strive for the cleanest code possible.

Comment: @Michael -- Style is style, if it looks clean to you then it is.  Welcome back.

Answer (score 2):

If you really have to use the C language (not C++) then you may use this workaround:

```
inline void ignore_result_helper(int __attribute__((unused)) dummy, ...)
{
}

#define IGNORE_RESULT(X) ignore_result_helper(0, (X))
```

For example

```
typedef struct A
{
    int x;
} A;

__attribute__((warn_unused_result)) A GetA()
{
    A const a;
    return a;
}

int main()
{
    IGNORE_RESULT(GetA());
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't *have* to use C, but I much prefer C to C++ :)

Comment: I wish that I could upvote that comment more than once ;-)